# Pandas dataframe：how to achieve that two rows are subtracted according to the keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
  id    Click_time  
0  a           3         
1  b           1         
2  a           4         
3  b           6         
4  a           8         
5  b           8
```

I want to get each id's interval between two clicks.  What I want to get is as follows:

```
      id    Click_time  interval
0  a           3         nan
1  b           1         nan
2  a           4         1
3  b           6         5
4  a           8         4
5  b           8         2
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Use `df['interval'] = df.groupby('id')['Click_time'].diff()`

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solves my problem.